# document multiple version of API using swaggydoc on grails with same controller name under separate directory

Tags: api, grails, swagger, grails-plugin, swagger-2.0

I'm using swaggydoc plugin on my grails application to document the REST APIs. I have two versions of API, v0 and v1 and corresponding controllers with same name, one for each version like:
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He09w.png)
and i have the Url mapping like `"/my2api/v1"(controller:"api",namespace:'v1')
 "/myapi/v0" (controller:"api", namespace:'v0')`
and getting both versions of the API endpoints listed as /myapi/v0/activeContracts [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voHZB.png).
So my question is, how can I get the API end point listed with correct URLs with corresponding versions like `/myapi/v0/activeContracts & /myapi/v1/activeContracts` as i mentioned I've tried the mapping but it ill just pickup the first the last mapping and assign it to both versions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration)? If not would love to get your feedback on it.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan I did came across it while looking around but I haven't tried it as I wanted to get the swaggydoc to work cuz thats already been used for a while in the app. How well does the SpringFox play with API versioning.?. Keeping in mind my use case, can i achieve this with springfox cuz I'm happy to try it and give you feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people facing the same prob, I couldn't find a solution using swaggyDocs and also came across some post suggesting it doesn't support API versioning so ended up switching to [Grails RestApiDoc](https://grails.org/plugin/rest-api-doc) which provides a lot more control (changing the API conf by just editing the json) than I was able to get on swaggyDocs. But please do post if someone knows a way to work it out in swaggyDoc.